# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'get' in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have this link with onClick function:

```
<a id="content-tmce" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" onclick="return_tinymce_status();">Visual</a>
```

When clicked, the editor will load tinymce again (from the original CodeMirror environment). This is the return_tinymce_status function:

```
function return_tinymce_status() {

    if (!(window.tinyMCE)) {        
        window.tinyMCE=tinymce;
    }

}
```

In Firefox, when I click the link, it is working fine without any errors in the JS console. However in Chrome, I get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'get'
```

Any special handling to the  JS window in Chrome? Or am I missing something simple here? This is where it points the error to:

```
var switchEditors={switchto:function(b){var c=b.id,a=c.length,e=c.substr(0,a-5),d=c.substr(a-4);this.go(e,d)},go:function(g,f){g=g||"content";f=f||"toggle";var c=this,b=tinyMCE.get(g),a,d,e=tinymce.DOM;a="wp-"+g+"-wrap";d=e.get(g);if("toggle"==f){if(b&&!b.isHidden()){f="html"}else{f="tmce"}}if("tmce"==f||"tinymce"==f){if(b&&!b.isHidden()){return false}if(typeof(QTags)!="undefined"){QTags.closeAllTags(g)}if(tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit[g]&&tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit[g].wpautop){d.value=c.wpautop(d.value)}if(b){b.show()}else{b=new tinymce.Editor(g,tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit[g]);b.render()}e.removeClass(a,"html-active");e.addClass(a,"tmce-active");setUserSetting("editor","tinymce")}else{if("html"==f){if(b&&b.isHidden()){return false}if(b){b.hide()}e.removeClass(a,"tmce-active");e.addClass(a,"html-active");setUserSetting("editor","html")}}return false},_wp_Nop:function(c){var d,b,e=false,a=false;if(c.indexOf("<pre")!=-1||c.indexOf("<script")!=-1){e=true;c=c.replace(/<(pre|script)[^>]*>[\s\S]+?<\/\1>/g,function(f){f=f.replace(/<br ?\/?>(\r\n|\n)?/g,"<wp-temp-lb>");return f.replace(/<\/?p( [^>]*)?>(\r\n|\n)?/g,"<wp-temp-lb>")})}if(c.indexOf("[caption")!=-1){a=true;c=c.replace(/\[caption[\s\S]+?\[\/caption\]/g,function(f){return f.replace(/<br([^>]*)>/g,"<wp-temp-br$1>").replace(/[\r\n\t]+/,"")})}d="blockquote|ul|ol|li|table|thead|tbody|tfoot|tr|th|td|div|h[1-6]|p|fieldset";c=c.replace(new RegExp("\\s*</("+d+")>\\s*","g"),"</$1>\n");c=c.replace(new RegExp("\\s*<((?:"+d+")(?: [^>]*)?)>","g"),"\n<$1>");c=c.replace(/(<p [^>]+>.*?)<\/p>/g,"$1</p#>");c=c.replace(/<div( [^>]*)?>\s*<p>/gi,"<div$1>\n\n");c=c.replace(/\s*<p>/gi,"");c=c.replace(/\s*<\/p>\s*/gi,"\n\n");c=c.replace(/\n[\s\u00a0]+\n/g,"\n\n");c=c.replace(/\s*<br ?\/?>\s*/gi,"\n");c=c.replace(/\s*<div/g,"\n<div");c=c.replace(/<\/div>\s*/g,"</div>\n");c=c.replace(/\s*\[caption([^\[]+)\[\/caption\]\s*/gi,"\n\n[caption$1[/caption]\n\n");c=c.replace(/caption\]\n\n+\[caption/g,"caption]\n\n[caption");b="blockquote|ul|ol|li|table|thead|tbody|tfoot|tr|th|td|h[1-6]|pre|fieldset";c=c.replace(new RegExp("\\s*<((?:"+b+")(?: [^>]*)?)\\s*>","g"),"\n<$1>");c=c.replace(new RegExp("\\s*</("+b+")>\\s*","g"),"</$1>\n");c=c.replace(/<li([^>]*)>/g,"\t<li$1>");if(c.indexOf("<hr")!=-1){c=c.replace(/\s*<hr( [^>]*)?>\s*/g,"\n\n<hr$1>\n\n")}if(c.indexOf("<object")!=-1){c=c.replace(/<object[\s\S]+?<\/object>/g,function(f){return f.replace(/[\r\n]+/g,"")})}c=c.replace(/<\/p#>/g,"</p>\n");c=c.replace(/\s*(<p [^>]+>[\s\S]*?<\/p>)/g,"\n$1");c=c.replace(/^\s+/,"");c=c.replace(/[\s\u00a0]+$/,"");if(e){c=c.replace(/<wp-temp-lb>/g,"\n")}if(a){c=c.replace(/<wp-temp-br([^>]*)>/g,"<br$1>")}return c},_wp_Autop:function(a){var c=false,b=false,d="table|thead|tfoot|caption|col|colgroup|tbody|tr|td|th|div|dl|dd|dt|ul|ol|li|pre|select|option|form|map|area|blockquote|address|math|style|p|h[1-6]|hr|fieldset|noscript|samp|legend|section|article|aside|hgroup|header|footer|nav|figure|figcaption|details|menu|summary";if(a.indexOf("<object")!=-1){a=a.replace(/<object[\s\S]+?<\/object>/g,function(e){return e.replace(/[\r\n]+/g,"")})}a=a.replace(/<[^<>]+>/g,function(e){return e.replace(/[\r\n]+/g," ")});if(a.indexOf("<pre")!=-1||a.indexOf("<script")!=-1){c=true;a=a.replace(/<(pre|script)[^>]*>[\s\S]+?<\/\1>/g,function(e){return e.replace(/(\r\n|\n)/g,"<wp-temp-lb>")})}if(a.indexOf("[caption")!=-1){b=true;a=a.replace(/\[caption[\s\S]+?\[\/caption\]/g,function(e){e=e.replace(/<br([^>]*)>/g,"<wp-temp-br$1>");e=e.replace(/<[a-zA-Z0-9]+( [^<>]+)?>/g,function(f){return f.replace(/[\r\n\t]+/," ")});return e.replace(/\s*\n\s*/g,"<wp-temp-br />")})}a=a+"\n\n";a=a.replace(/<br \/>\s*<br \/>/gi,"\n\n");a=a.replace(new RegExp("(<(?:"+d+")(?: [^>]*)?>)","gi"),"\n$1");a=a.replace(new RegExp("(</(?:"+d+")>)","gi"),"$1\n\n");a=a.replace(/<hr( [^>]*)?>/gi,"<hr$1>\n\n");a=a.replace(/\r\n|\r/g,"\n");a=a.replace(/\n\s*\n+/g,"\n\n");a=a.replace(/([\s\S]+?)\n\n/g,"<p>$1</p>\n");a=a.replace(/<p>\s*?<\/p>/gi,"");a=a.replace(new RegExp("<p>\\s*(</?(?:"+d+")(?: [^>]*)?>)\\s*</p>","gi"),"$1");a=a.replace(/<p>(<li.+?)<\/p>/gi,"$1");a=a.replace(/<p>\s*<blockquote([^>]*)>/gi,"<blockquote$1><p>");a=a.replace(/<\/blockquote>\s*<\/p>/gi,"</p></blockquote>");a=a.replace(new RegExp("<p>\\s*(</?(?:"+d+")(?: [^>]*)?>)","gi"),"$1");a=a.replace(new RegExp("(</?(?:"+d+")(?: [^>]*)?>)\\s*</p>","gi"),"$1");a=a.replace(/\s*\n/gi,"<br />\n");a=a.replace(new RegExp("(</?(?:"+d+")[^>]*>)\\s*<br />","gi"),"$1");a=a.replace(/<br \/>(\s*<\/?(?:p|li|div|dl|dd|dt|th|pre|td|ul|ol)>)/gi,"$1");a=a.replace(/(?:<p>|<br ?\/?>)*\s*\[caption([^\[]+)\[\/caption\]\s*(?:<\/p>|<br ?\/?>)*/gi,"[caption$1[/caption]");a=a.replace(/(<(?:div|th|td|form|fieldset|dd)[^>]*>)(.*?)<\/p>/g,function(f,e,g){if(g.match(/<p( [^>]*)?>/)){return f}return e+"<p>"+g+"</p>"});if(c){a=a.replace(/<wp-temp-lb>/g,"\n")}if(b){a=a.replace(/<wp-temp-br([^>]*)>/g,"<br$1>")}return a},pre_wpautop:function(b){var a=this,d={o:a,data:b,unfiltered:b},c=typeof(jQuery)!="undefined";if(c){jQuery("body").trigger("beforePreWpautop",[d])}d.data=a._wp_Nop(d.data);if(c){jQuery("body").trigger("afterPreWpautop",[d])}return d.data},wpautop:function(b){var a=this,d={o:a,data:b,unfiltered:b},c=typeof(jQuery)!="undefined";if(c){jQuery("body").trigger("beforeWpautop",[d])}d.data=a._wp_Autop(d.data);if(c){jQuery("body").trigger("afterWpautop",[d])}return d.data}};
```

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:** By the way after executing the function "return_tinymce_status()" it goes to this line of code:

```
  $('.switch-tmce').click(function() {

  //Visual editor is activated
  //Turn off Code Mirror        
  editor.toggleCodeMirror('content', false);                
  switchEditors.switchto(this);

  });
```

Maybe it has something do with "this".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this. Instead of using this:

```
<a id="content-tmce" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" onclick="return_tinymce_status();">Visual</a>
```

I remove the onclick function using jQuery so the result is this:

```
<a id="content-tmce" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" onclick="">Visual</a>
```

This is by using jQUery:

```
$('.switch-tmce').attr('onclick', '');
```

Then run that function (return_tinymce_status) within jQuery click event:

```
       $('.switch-tmce').click(function() {

            return_tinymce_status();

       });
```

Error is gone. Problem solved. I hope this helps someone.